# Can you use android chromecast apis for a standalone java program?

Tags: chromecast

Android chromecast api are in java..so in the theory they could be used in arbitrary java programs...am I correct?

My intention would be to build a chromecast streaming server in java, so to stream local files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to use Cast APIs, you will not be able to do that; most of the functionality is in the Google Play services.

Comment: Seems strange to me anyways as I think there should be some java api to interact with google play services.

Comment: Google Play services is a library on your phone, so I am not sure I understand what you mean by "interacting" with that when you are running on a different device.

Comment: Ups sorry I misunderstood...I though you were referring to google play's server side, the one that is contacted by both android and google chrome's apis. As we are talking about protocols and messages from server's perspective there should be no difference between a javascript call (made by google chrome) and a java call (made by a java desktop program)

Comment: @AliNaddaf what about devices that don't have Google Play Services?

Comment: Those devices don't have access to any APIs that is provided by the Google Play services.