# Can a Chromecast sender be a standalone Java application?

Tags: chromecast

I'm trying to figure out the Google Chromecast platform and it looks like only iOS, Android and Chrome apps could cast to a Chromecast. Can a standalone Java application cast as well?

Comment: As also stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297727/5832311), Cast SDK is only available on Android, iOS and Chrome. You may also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995878/can-you-use-android-chromecast-apis-for-a-standalone-java-program) for additional reference. Also, see if your issue has already been filed in the [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205). If not, you may file a [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190205&template=814901) about it.